# When I build my solution its response is 1 error. But it is empty in the error list so can't see what the error is

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

How is this possible? In the build response there is one error but when I look at the error list nothing there.

Could it be that I need to download some packages for that function? Cause I am using the new ASP.NET Core 1.0. But when I take away a ";" sign somewhere the error list suddenly works. So it does work but what could the problem be ?

[image]

Comment: Since you've provided no actual code, I'm going to guess it's that `;` you removed. You should probably print it out on paper, take the paper out back, and beat it to within an inch of its life as punishment.

Comment: What else does it say in your Output window? It might not be a compilation error, but something else listed in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a visual studio thing that happens sometimes, happened to me today in fact, close visual studio and reopen it.